# How to update a class properly in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When I update or add a constructor in a class, Eclipse doesnt update the class in other scrapbook which I imported the class before.

For example my class code is like this;

```
public class Car{
    public Car(){
       super();
   }
}
```

In an scrapbook I import this class an create a Car instance. But when I try to update my original class to this and try to create another Car instance;

```
public class Car(){
    public Car(String brand, String year){
        super();
        this.brand= brand;
        this.year= year;
    }
}
```

It gives me the error "The constructor Car(String, String) is undefined".

The error goes away after I close and re-open Eclipse one time. Can someone help me how to update a class properly.

Comment: verify that you have compiled class Car after updating it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases the main cause is that you didn't save the `Car.java` file. Remember to press `Ctrl+S` every time you edited a file.